# Move file from between subfolders under folder level

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have around 200 folders mapped to a drive, we will call D:. Within the 200 folders on D: they have four main folders, two of which are the current and expired folders. My question is, is there a way I can write a script to go through the 200 folders, and copy the one document from current to the expired folder on that level. After this step, I would like to rename the document in the current folder to remove the date (11 characters).

ex.

```
Copy D:\Client\Current\Current Quote 09 30 2014.docx --> D:\Client\Expired\Current Quote 09 30 2014.docx
Rename D:\Client\Current\Current Quote 09 30 2014.docx --> D:\Client\Current\Current Quote.docx
```

Thanks you in advance for your suggestions,

Jordan

Comment: So you have `D:\Client1\...`, ..., `D:\client200\...`?

Comment: Stephan that is correct. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will cover it, but it should at least set you in the right direction. It's a bit unclear if you have multiple files that you need to handle, or just one with potentially varying dates.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    pushd %%a\current
    for %%f in (filename*) do (
        copy "%%f" ..\expired
        set fn=%%~nf
        set fn=!fn:~0,-11!
        ren "%%f" "!fn!%%xf"
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. There is usually one current rate, but sometimes there is two (user error, or the new rate has been created when it's not yet effective).